# How does the electron cloud amplitude of complex atoms decay?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

In quantum mechanics, when a particle is in a bound state with a finite binding energy, the amplitude of the wave function decays exponentially with distance with the decay length inversely proportional to the square root of the binding energy. For example, in hydrogen atoms the radial part of the electron wave function is an exponent multiplied by a polynomial. When the r is sufficiently large, the polynomial can be ignored and the amplitude decay is asymptotically exponential. As the principal quantum number increases, the binding energy decreases while the decay length increases. Other bound states like finite spherical wells follow the same rule.
$$ R_{1,0}(r)=2a_{0}^{-3/2}e^{-r/a_{0}}$$
$$ R_{2,0}(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a_0^{-3/2}(1-\frac{r}{2a_0})e^{-r/2a_0}$$
$$ R_{2,1}(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{24}}a_0^{-3/2}\frac{r}{a_{0}}e^{-r/2a_{0}}$$
If an atom has more than one electrons, will the wave function decay follow a similar pattern? While no analytical solutions are found, we should be able to numerically solve the Schrodinger equation at a high precision for very light atoms like helium. The question is whether their wave functions also decay exponentially at sufficiently large distances, and at what rate do they decay? For example, the 1st ionization energy of helium atom is 24.59 eV, while the average of the 1st and 2nd ionization energies is 39.50 eV. Considering that the 2 electrons of helium atoms share the same orbital, will the decay length be in better match with 24.59 or 39.50?

Comment: Just speaking qualitatively, for a neutral atom the long range behavior of the "outter" electrons should be exponential since from far away the nucleus just looks like a proton.

Comment: AfterShave is correct. The necessity for this behaviour is actually reflecting badly on most approximation schemes, because if you fill in the orbitals from deep electrons outwards, only the outermost electron would decay in the correct form, but we know that it should be that ALL the electrons should decay in the correct form. The literature doesn't seem to present the behaviour from numerically exact solutions to the actual problem, so you might need to find it out yourself.